# Why is Logging going in an infinite Loop?

Tags: python, logging

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import sys
import copy

class Wrapper:
    def write(self, s):
        #sys.__stdout__.write(s)
        loggy = logging.getLogger('foobar')
        loggy.info(s)

def blah():
    logger = logging.getLogger('foobar')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    streamhandle = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    streamhandle.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(message)s]'))
    logger.addHandler(streamhandle)

    sys.stdout = Wrapper()
    sys.stderr = Wrapper()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    blah()
    logger = logging.getLogger('')
    #print logger.handlers
    #for handler in logger.handlers:
    #    print handler

    fooy = logging.getLogger('foobar')
    #print fooy.handlers

    sys.stdout.write('i love you')

    logging.log(logging.DEBUG, 'i love you')
```

This code causes python to go in an infinite recursive loop,  and the output is actually incredibly cool:

```
[Error in sys.exitfunc:
]
[INFO:foobar:Error in sys.exitfunc:

]
[INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:Error in sys.exitfunc:


]
[INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:Error in sys.exitfunc:



]
[INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:Error in sys.exitfunc:




]
[INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:INFO:foobar:Error in sys.exitfunc:
```

This keeps growing exponentially :) Its pretty but why is this happening?

Comment: That is growing linearly, not exponentially.

Answer (score 6):

The infinite loop is happening because your logger's `StreamHandler` is set to write its log messages to `sys.stdout`, but `sys.stdout` is in turn wrapped and writes back to the very logger that just sent it a write message.

Depending on your goals, you're probably better having the `Wrapper` actually perform output, rather than use logging internally. Something like:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def write(self, s):
        sys.__stdout__.write(s) # sys.__stdout__ points to the original stdout, rather
                                # than the redirected sys.stdout
```

Comment: If i change this to: 

streamhandle = logging.StreamHandler(sys.__stdout__) so it now points to the orignal sys.stdout. This doesnt fix the issue but why?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean "this does fix the issue, but why?" or "this does not fix the issue... why?"

Comment: It doesn't fix the issue. Since this streamhandler is pointing to the orignal sys.stdout, why should this be calling the wrapper?

Comment: Not sure... I entered the code you have above, and substituted StreamHandler(sys.__stdout__), and it's working quite nicely.